# Does anyone have Adaptive Huffman compression for C#?

Tags: c#, huffman-code, adaptive-compression

Does anyone see this kind of source code over the Internet?

I have tried Google, it seems no where having this.

Is Adaptive Huffman encoder good?

Or

Anyone can share with me about the source code (C#) for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did a Google search for ["C#" adaptive huffman encoding]. On the first page of results:

This looks like it might do what you want: [Dynamic Huffman Encoding in C#](http://anotherdev.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/dynamic-huffman-encoding-in-c/).

There's also some source code on this benchmarks site (second page of search results) http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~ckrintz/racelab/PhxCSBenchmarks/index.html. In the area where it has the Adaptive Huffman Encoding benchmark, there's a link to the source code (either .zip or tar.gz)

I'd be surprised to find that either one is better than the built-in `GZipStream` or `DeflateStream`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compress stuff, C# already has [compression libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, c# gzip deflate are not so good. Also I am trying to see some characteristics of Adaptive Huffman coding, so I ask

Comment: What do you mean by "not so good"? Is there a specific problem you're having with it? Typically, a normal implementation of deflate will out-perform huffman.

Comment: Well, I don't know, lol. My supervisor needs me to compare Adaptive Huffman coding to other things, and "Adaptive Huffman" is what he specified. So I have to do.

Comment: Tell your supervisor to put you to work on those TPS reports.

Comment: Jack, the question is whether they're good enough for the task at hand. Have you measured the performance (speed and size) of the .Net libraries for your problem domain? What criteria do you have that they are failing to meet?

Comment: I just want to compare several compressors directly. The criteria is the size of the compressed file.